# Error con webservices: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException

Tags: java, apache, xml, java-ee

he creado un cliente de *webservice en java* a partir del *wsdl*, sobre

### tomcat7 y axis2

Al crear la clase para invocar las operaciones (métodos) del webservice me da el Error:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Message: Nombre de codificación
>   no válido "".

Alguien que pueda orientarme?
Gracias.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[-1,-1]
Message: Nombre de codificación no válido "".
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:347)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba el xml request que estás enviando, ese error se debe a que el servicio no está entendiendo algo de la estructura de lo que envías.

Por ejemplo

Si el request es

```
<startDate>""</startDate>
```

Pero el servicio espera un tipo Date(), habrá problemas por que no hay compatilidad de datos.

Si el request es

```
<tag_1>"10:00"</tag_1>
```

Pero el servicio espera una etiqueta 'Tag_1'

Si el request es

```
<tag_1>"10:00"</tag_1>
```

Pero el servicio espera Tag_1 y startDate.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, ya he mapeado los datos del request que estoy enviando, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo Error.